# Select company name into query in multi company database

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

This is what I want to do with focus on `CompanyName`:

```
SELECT 'Companyname', [Date], [Net Amount] FROM [Company1$Transaction Header]
```

Where `Companyname` is the company name in the `FROM` condition `[Company1$Transaction Header]`

Is this possible?

--EDIT

After checking Bluefeet suggestions, I´m leaning towards something like this:

What do you think?

```
DECLARE @CompanyName
SET @CompanyName = (SELECT statement that gets the CompanyName)
SELECT @CompanyName, [Date], [Net amount], FROM [Company1@Transaction Header]
```

Comment: So the `companyName` is part of the name of the table?  Are you using MySQL or SQL Server?  The square brackets are in SQL Server but you tagged this MySQL?

Comment: Yes, the companyName is part of the name of the table. Ooops :)

Comment: What database are you using?

Comment: Testing on a Cronus multiple company database. SQL2008R2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to extract the CompanyName from the table name, then you can use the [`information_schema`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186224.aspx) views to get the data:

```
select left(table_name, charindex('$', table_name)-1) Company
from information_schema.tables
where table_name ='Company1$Transaction Header';
```

Then you can use this inside of a query:

```
select c.company,
  date, 
  netamount
from [Company1$Transaction Header]
cross join
(
  select left(table_name, charindex('$', table_name)-1) Company
  from information_schema.tables
  where table_name ='Company1$Transaction Header'
) c;
```

If you will know ahead of time the name of the company and table, then you can just include the company name in the query as a static string:

```
select 'Company1' CompanyName,
  date, 
  netamount
from [Company1$Transaction Header]
```

Comment: Keep getting empty data results. 
I should replace my tablename with the example right?
CRONUS(6_1)W1 Demo-v3$Transaction Header

Comment: Yes, you wil have to replace the table with your table name.

Comment: @AceAlfred It is the same thing that my query is doing except you are using a parameter.  But my question is that if you know the CompanyName from the table name, why not just use a string to include it in the final result?

Comment: Yes you are right, but I´m using the query within a .NET function where it picks up each unique companyname table, just wanting the whole thing working without hard coding it in.